# What constitutes humor on this "i before e" coffee mug text?

Tags: orthography, phrase-meaning, humor

I saw this writing on a coffee mug, which is supposedly popular amongst linguists:

> ### i before e
>
> Except after C
> and also when you
> heinously seize your
> feisty foreign neighbor's
> conceited beige heifer
> from the ceiling.
> Weird.

I don't get the humor; could someone, please, spell(no pun intended) it out for me?

Comment: The mug lists a rule and then drops in 10 exceptions to it.

Comment: Is "spell" a joke here?

Comment: @Peter Shor I did not intend it to be. I really want to understand the humor in the quoted text

Comment: [... and on weekends, and holidays...](https://youtu.be/QWzYaZDK6Is?t=56)

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C

Comment: @YosefBaskin  How many?

Comment: @PhilSweet - Ah, eight + *conceited* and *ceiling*.

Comment: I share your puzzlement.  I get the point, but do not find it all that funny.  Strictly, the humour is not a matter of usage, except to the extent that English spelling is itself amusingly erratic, which is what the examples amply illustrate.

Comment: It's not so much humour as a *contrivance* to put all those exceptions in one sentence.

Comment: The way I learned the supposed rule was "I before E / Except after C / Or when sounded like A / as in *neighbor* or *weigh."* Per that version, three of the mug's counter-examples are not counter-examples at all. (Is it coincidence that the three are consecutive?)

Comment: would have been more fun if it said "i.e." and then listing examples.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'd replace *conceited* and *ceiling* with *ancient* and *glacier*, just to make it even more confusing.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman Yes, that'd be really confusing ;-)

Comment: Why people find things funny belongs, perhaps, on [psychology.stackexchange](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/5625/how-does-our-brain-consider-something-to-be-funny). For me, it was the sudden jolt of understanding that led me to let out a big guffaw. Perhaps no joke is funny if it needs to be spelled out to you bit by bit...

Comment: The wording on the mug (or should I say "stein"?) would have been more impressive if the person who composed it had replaced "conceited" with "leisurely" and "from the ceiling" with "under the veil."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"i before e except after c"* is a spelling "rule" that many people remember from school or just because it's often repeated. It refers to words like "p**ie**ce" to help people remember the "ie" order, and words like "con**cei**ve," where the "e" follows a "c" and is before the "i", like some similar words. But there are many exceptions to the "rule." The text on the mug lists many of these exceptions, and  strings them together into a weird little story, so it's a clever and surprising refutation of the "rule." That makes the mug either funny, or for some people who have trouble with spelling, tragic.

- The full "rule" is often quoted as: "i before e, except after C, or when sounded as 'a' as in neighbor and weigh"

Comment: Every rule about the English language has an exception... except this one.

Comment: HA ha. Of course that's right.

Comment: Convenient isn't a good example because the the _ie_ there is a diphthong.  Better examples are niece, fiend, and piece, among others, and perhaps words like lie, pie, and tie.

Comment: @phoog And "_lie_" suggests its own counterexample to the rule: "_lei_" (garland of flowers and – I've just discovered – an urn-shaped Chinese bronze wine-vessel of the Shang to Middle Chou period, according to the OED).

Comment: I hope you'll switch to a better example than "convenient."  See https://www.lexico.com/grammar/i-before-e-except-after-c.

Comment: As I understand it the i-before-e "rule" is true less than half of the time, so really it *is* the exception.

Comment: @ColleenV '... except this one.'  This, of course makes your rule a self-referencing *meta-exception* thereby effectively making it no longer exceptional    :-D

Comment: @TripeHound They're not true counter-examples, though  because  the garland is a loan word from Hawaiian and the bronze jar isn't common enough in English even to be a proper loan word.  'Their" is probably the most common counter-example.

Comment: @BoldBen True. I did nearly add its Hawaiian origin, and I'd never heard the "jar" meaning until I checked the OED. It was just that the juxtaposition of lie/lei struck me.

Comment: Maybe expand on "east to remember spelling rule" to say it's famous -- the one spelling rule most Americans(?) remember from school?

Comment: I will say in partial defense of this rule that the full version goes "...or when sounding like 'ay' as in 'neighbor' or 'weigh'" (which covers 3 of the "exceptions" on the mug).

Comment: @MissMonicaE: We learnt it as "... when the sound is 'ee'", which also rules out most of the exceptions :)

Comment: It's a w*ei*rd rule anyway.

Comment: I've heard the exception both ways: The "ay" version of the rule makes it not apply to *heinously*, *neighbor*, and *beige*; while the "ee" version makes it additionally not apply to *feisty*, *foreign*, and *heifer*.

Answer (score 7):

user8356's answer correctly describes the meaning behind the text on the mug.

As for the "humor," I would agree with Weather Vane's comment—if the mug is "funny" at all, it is not "ha-ha funny" like a knock-knock joke. Rather it is the [comic irony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony#Comic_irony) of the mug laying out a supposed "rule" and then listing many exceptions which make the mug humorous, if "humorous" is even the right word.

Comment: Well, I let out a big guffaw as I read through it and the point hit me. Just seighing...

Comment: 'Comic irony' and the mentioning of the POB debate over how funny this is form the correct answer here.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct, but I want to add that I always heard the full rule stated as:

> I before E, except after C, except words that sound like "A", as in neighbor and weigh

So the mug is just replacing the last part of the rhyme with an absurd list of other words that also break the rule, highlighting that even this rule is broken numerous times in English, beyond the additional words sounding like "A".  The rule as stated above is meant as a rule of thumb, that is, not as a logically or fully complete rule, as that would be nearly impossible in the context of a simple rhyme.

The humor is directed at the English language itself and the many ways it breaks its own rules.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I meant "full rule" as in the full wording of the "I before E" rule as I've often heard it, not in the sense that the rule was comprehensive or complete in itself.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Point taken.  I have edited my answer to better clarify that the rule is not meant to be an absolute and complete rule.

Comment: Thanks, Sarah. Welcome to ELU, by the way. (I deleted '(a belated one)' and '(belatedly)' there. This place can take over.)